# How can I set up onClickListener on Toast?

Tags: android, toast

Is there way to set up `onClickLister` on `Toast`? I tried set it on toast, on custom view, on imageView in the custom view, but its doesn't work. If its impossible is there alternative variant to do it more simply that create little dialogs or view?

Comment: Why whould you need that?

Comment: i my case i need allow user come in the next fragment by information in toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check [**Crouton**](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) . this might help you.

Comment: this library is deprecated @AnikIslamAbhi

Comment: it is far most better to use the snack bar

Answer (score 0):

I think You are talking about the snack bar. Which looks like toast. and yo can perform any action through that and it looks really well on devices.

If that is the case, [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) you can read about them . And [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/) nice tutorial about snack bar.

You can also use material design snack bar using design library . [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/) you go.